# How can I resolve the schemaLocation attribute of an .XSD when all of my .XSD's are stored as resources?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0, xsd

I am working on a project where I need to generate XML files based on nested XSD's.  e.g. ORDER has a reference to PERSON, PERSON has a reference to ADDRESS, etc.

I am creating an `XmlReaderSettings' instance to validate the XSD's, as well as validate the XML after it is generated.

I have added the XSD's as Resources to my assembly.  I then create an `XmlSchema` instance for each resource, from lowest to highest, and add it to the `XmlReaderSettings.Schemas` collection.

However, this fails attempting to add a schema that references another schema.  I get an XmlSchemaException: "For element declaration, either the name or the ref attribute must be present."

I have included sample XSD's and source code below:

**ADDRESS.xsd** - referenced by PERSON.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="ADDRESS.xsd" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ADDRESS" >
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ADDRESS1" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="ADDRESS2" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="CITY" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="STATE" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="ZIP" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**PERSON.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="PERSON.xsd" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="ADDRESS.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="PERSON" >
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="L_NAME" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="F_NAME" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Addresses">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="ADDRESS" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Sample Code** - Load and validate XSD's

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using SchemaTest.Properties;

namespace SchemaTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create validation settings instance
            var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
            {
                ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
                ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema |
                                  XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation |
                                  XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings
            };

            xmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler += SchemaValidationEventHandler;

            // added XmlResourceResolver, per the accepted answer below
            xMLReaderSettings.Schemas.XmlResolver = new XmlResourceResolver();

            // load schemas into validation settings instance
            LoadSchema(xmlReaderSettings, Resources.PERSON);

            // validate schemas
            xmlReaderSettings.Schemas.Compile();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void LoadSchema(XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings, string schemaString)
        {
            using (var schemaStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(schemaString)))
            {
                var schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaStream, null);

                try
                {
                    xmlReaderSettings.Schemas.Add(schema);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: {0}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void SchemaValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", e.Severity, e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this has anything to do with the `ValidationFlags`, but I tried removing `XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation` and still received the same error.  I have also tried passing `SchemaValidationEventHandler` to the `XmlSchema.Read` method (instead of null in sample code), and the schema seems to be created OK, but it still throws the exception when attemtping to add it to the `XmlReaderSettings.Schemas` collection.

**EDIT - 2011.11.03**

I resolved this issue (pun intended) by creating my own `XmlUrlResolver` descendent called `XmlResourceResolver`, based on the `XmlResolver` class example in accepted answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get rid of the error, change type="Addresses" to name="Addresses" in your PERSON.xsd file.

It is better to go with the code below to get schemas compiled. The important things are to make sure you establish a base uri (since you're reading from a stream), to use an XmlSchemaSet instead, and a custom resolver (to read files as embedded resources).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        class XmlResolver : XmlUrlResolver
        {
            internal const string BaseUri = "schema://";

            public override object GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, string role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
            {
                if (absoluteUri.Scheme == "schema")
                {
                    switch (absoluteUri.LocalPath)
                    {
                        case "/ADDRESS.xsd":
                            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Resource.ADDRESS));
                        case "/PERSON.xsd":
                            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Resource.PERSON));
                    }
                }
                return base.GetEntity(absoluteUri, role, ofObjectToReturn);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(Resource.PERSON), new XmlReaderSettings(), XmlResolver.BaseUri))
            {
                XmlSchemaSet xset = RetrieveSchemaSet(reader);
                Console.WriteLine(xset.IsCompiled);
            }
        }

        private static XmlSchemaSet RetrieveSchemaSet(XmlReader reader)
        {
            XmlSchemaSet xset = new XmlSchemaSet() { XmlResolver = new XmlResolver() };
            xset.Add(XmlSchema.Read(reader, null));
            xset.Compile();
            return xset;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the `XmlResolver` did the trick.  I used your example to create my own custom resolver, and refactored my code to assign the resolver to my `xmlReaderSettings.Schemas` schema set.