# Dealing with xsd:include XSDs as an embedded resource in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, xsd, embedded-resource

I have a set of XSDs that validate against XMLSPY and against Java code.  I need to bring this set of XSDs as an embedded resource in Visual Studio 2012 .net.  Unfortunately I am getting an error that a global element has already been declared when trying to resolve them with a custom XmlResolver to deal with the xsd:include.  Error is strange because the element is declared only once.

```
Visual Studio Solution
    |-----------    Visual Studio Project
            |-----------    Schemas (Embedded Resource)
                    |-----------    Directory A
                            |------------ set of XSDs that are referenced by XSDs in Directory B and to a globaltype definition file located in this directory
                    |-----------    Directory B
                            |------------- set of XSDs that reference each other and those in Directory A, the XSD call from the main is located here
```

Validating Util Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace ABC.XYZ.Utils
{
    public static class XmlUtil
    {
        private static bool isValid;

        public static bool ValidateXml(string targetNamespace, string schemaUri, string xml)
        {
            isValid = true;

            var schemaReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings() { ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema };
            schemaReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler += MyValidationHandler;

            schemaReaderSettings.Schemas.XmlResolver = new XmlResourceResolver();
            var schemaReader = XmlReader.Create(GetSchemaStream(schemaUri), schemaReaderSettings);
            schemaReaderSettings.Schemas.Add(targetNamespace, schemaReader);

            var x = XElement.Parse(xml);
            var sr = new System.IO.StringReader(x.ToString());

            XmlReader validatingReader = XmlReader.Create(sr, schemaReaderSettings);

            while (validatingReader.Read())
            {
            }

            validatingReader.Close();

            return isValid;
        }

        private static void MyValidationHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("***Validation error");
            Console.WriteLine("\tSeverity:{0}", args.Severity);
            Console.WriteLine("\tMessage:{0}", args.Message);
            isValid = false;
        }

        private static Stream GetSchemaStream(string relativeFileName)
        {
            var resourceFileName =
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .GetManifestResourceNames()
                    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.EndsWith(relativeFileName));
            return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceFileName);
        }

    }
}
```

Custom XmlResolver

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace ABC.XYZ.Utils
{
    public class XmlResourceResolver : XmlResolver
    {
        public const string AssemblyDefaultNamespace = "ABC.XYZ";
        public const string SchemasNamespace = "Schemas";

        public override Uri ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, string relativeUri)
        {
            var result = new UriBuilder("res://", AssemblyDefaultNamespace, -1, SchemasNamespace.Replace(".", "/"));
            result.Path += "/" + relativeUri.Replace("../", "/").TrimStart('/');
            return result.Uri;
        }

        public override object GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, string role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
        {
            if (absoluteUri.Scheme != "res") return null;
            Debug.WriteLine("Loading resource based on location {0}", absoluteUri);

            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var name = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}",
                absoluteUri.Host,
                absoluteUri.GetComponents(UriComponents.PathAndQuery, UriFormat.Unescaped).Replace("/", "."));

            // try for an exact match based on schemaLocation hint path
            var resourceName = (from x in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
                                where name.Equals(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                select x).FirstOrDefault();

            // if not match based on filename alone
            if (resourceName == null)
            {
                var schemaDocumentName = Path.GetFileName(absoluteUri.AbsolutePath);
                Debug.WriteLine("Unable to locate exact match, looking for match based on filename {0}", schemaDocumentName);
                resourceName = (from x in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
                                where x.Contains(SchemasNamespace) && 
                                      x.EndsWith("." + schemaDocumentName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                select x).FirstOrDefault();
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Loading resource {0}", resourceName);
            var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
            return stream;
        }
    }

}
```

Any insights into this problem with be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

XSD 1.0 encourages but does not require validators to detect multiple inclusions (or imports) of the same schema document and include them only once.

The result is that including the same schema document more than once from multiple other schema documents is the simplest way to create interoperability nightmares with XSD.  (Not the only way, just the simplest way.)  If you own the schema documents, segregate all inclusions and all schema-location information on imports into a driver file and delete all includes and all schema-location hints on imports from the 'normal' schema documents.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you're doing it with XMLSpy, the XSDs are files in the file system; what's happening then, for each file there's a base URI, and therefore resolvers will use that information to ensure that once an XSD is loaded, the same one is not loaded again, based on URI compare.

Now, the way you're doing it by loading as a stream from an assembly, all that information is gone (your stream doesn't have a base URI). Your resolver will keep loading the same XSD over and over again, from different places, thus creating this clash.

All the XSD processors I know, do not employ any other means to filter multiple inclusions of the same XSD content, but base source URI.

In .NET, the easiest way might be (again, depending on how complex your graph is) to try the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982275/how-can-i-resolve-the-schemalocation-attribute-of-an-xsd-when-all-of-my-xsds); the whole idea is to provide a base URI, which should give the info required to avoid multiple inclusions.

Another alternative might be to make sure in your custom resolver that for any given URI you're resolving, you only return once a stream (return null in all other cases). This is guaranteed to work as long as you're not using xsd:redefine composition (in which case the solution is to make a topological sort of the schema file graph and ensure all xsd:redefines are loaded first).

To @CMSperbergMcQueen point, an approach that is guaranteed to work is to refactor ALL the XSDs such that there's only one XSD embedded resource per namespace; each XSD would have all imports removed (technique called "dangling"). Add those XSDs to an XML Schema set as independent XSDs and compile. Unless you run into a .NET bug, the result should be a compiled XmlSchemaSet.